# Xamarin.Android Binding an AAR generated from Go - how to handle tuple returns?

Tags: java, go, binding, xamarin.android

I try to create a Xamarin.Android-Bindings Project for the following AAR:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/storj/libuplink-android/0.6/

It basically works. But the problem is that the included Java code got generated from Go-Code and it seems that all functions returning a tuple are not included in the binding. See this function:
https://github.com/storj/storj/blob/057d30152c80847a4edb0e7e91c31b012108b6ff/mobile/uplink.go#L65

This gets generated.

But the following does not (as it returns a tuple?):
https://github.com/storj/storj/blob/057d30152c80847a4edb0e7e91c31b012108b6ff/mobile/uplink.go#L44

Is this something a can overcome by specifying something in the metadata.xml? Anything else I can do?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, wait. If I decompile the Java included in the AAR I see that those functions are not included. So the Problem is not within the Binding-Project, it's the AAr itself.

Comment: Ok, Please ignore that Question. The missing functions are included in a different Namespace where those Special cases are handled. All fine!